# VS Code Autocomplete not coming after typing a Keyword JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, keyword, javascript-intellisense

My problem is that in VS Code after I type four particular keywords -> 'var', 'let', 'const', 'function', VS Code Intellisense for JavaScript/Typescript stop working and only starts working again if I end the statement with a semicolon equal to or braces. Only the snippets appear in the list after typing these keywords. I don't like to add semicolons at the end of a statement so pls help me out.

> [image: Blockquote]

As you can see when I type Hello , Intellisense is not working. This problem was not there when I first installed VS Code.

Comment: Also pls tell if there is a  VS Code settings property for this.

Comment: please help anyone??